# Unity Andriod: Application looses focus on Inputfield

Tags: c#, android, database, unity-game-engine

My App uses Firebase Database and I need to know when a User closes the App (to remove them from the room,...).
Currently, I use OnApplicationFocus:

```
  private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
    {
        if(!focus)
            LeaveGame();
        else if(_gameID == "" && _reJoinGameID != "")
            TryReJoinGame();
    }
```

This all works fine, but when a User clicks on an Inputfield, the Keyboard pops up, the App loses focus and the User is back in the main menu. After that the App reconnects and the User in again in front of the empty uneditable Inputfield.

I tried:
OnApplicationQuit - does not trigger.
OnApplicationPause - works some times, but is not reliable.

Is there a way to bypass the focus loss on the Inputfield or is there a different and better way to handle this situation?

Comment: you could add a "went to input" boolean... so if went to boolean then dont leave/reconnect